# Meaning of the word - בָּרָ֣א

Tags: translation, tetragrammaton, gods, elohim

In **Genisis 1:1** the reason the English Bible uses the word **"God"** instead of **"Gods"** for **"Elohim"** is the word בָּרָ֣א  . Which translates from Hebrew as **"son"** or **"child"** and sometimes as **"to create"**.

If we accept the "son" or "child", the verse talks about **the Son of the Gods(plural)**, but then says **nothing about creating anything**.
If we accept "to create", the verse talks about **the Gods(plural) creating heaven and earth.**

Also **Psalms 82:1** says "God stands in the **assembly of Gods**, He judges **among Gods**".
**Genesis 11:7** says "Come, **let Us** go down...".

Is **Yhwh** then just **one of** Christianity's gods or is **He** just the one out of **all the Gods** we chose **?**